# How to check the dtypes of all columns in a df are same or not in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-types

I am new to Pandas, I wanted to check if all the columns of df are same or not. However, I tried to do but though I Am getting an error

```
print(df.columns)
Index(['age', 'car', 'car_name'], dtype='object')
```

where age, car is int, float and car_name is an object

```
for i in df:
    if df[i].dtypes == int or df[i].dtypes == float:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
this gives:
yes
yes
no
```

but what I want is to give on the whole, like if  all column have int or float it should print yes else no. (by using `if else` condition)

excepted output:

```
for i in df:
        if all column of df == int or all column of df == float:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')
output: 'No'
```

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: `df.dtypes.drop_duplicates().shape[0]== 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or perhaps check whether where are more than 1 `dtypes`:

```
df.dtypes.nunique()>1
```

Will return `True` if your df has different dtypes.

Comment: how to get the dtype of that unique type?

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_same(df):
    # this method returns true if all types are same, else returns false
    no_of_types = len(df.dtypes.unique())
    is_same = no_of_types == 1
    return is_same

diff_types1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2,3,4], "c": ["A", "C", "E"]})
diff_types2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2.0,3.1,4.2], "c": [2, 4, 5]})
same_types = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2,3,4], "c": [2, 4, 5]})
same_types2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["A", "C", "E"], "b": ["A", "C", "E"], "c": ["A", "C", "E"]})

is_same(diff_types1)
# False

is_same(diff_types2)
# False

is_same(same_types1)
# True

is_same(same_types2)
# True
```

Comment: I actually wanted in if and else condition is that possible? like if columns of df is int/float then print'yes'

Comment: i added another answer which gives true or false if types are all numeric or not

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
df.dtypes.drop_duplicates().shape[0]== 1
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['a'] = 1, 2, 3
>>> df['b'] = 4, 5, 6
>>> df.dtypes.drop_duplicates().shape[0]== 1
True
>>> df['b'] = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
>>> df.dtypes.drop_duplicates().shape[0]== 1
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
def is_int_or_float(df):
    # this method returns true if all types are numeric
    is_numeric_types = sum([is_numeric_dtype(x) for x in df])
    return is_numeric_types

diff_types1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2,3,4], "c": ["A", "C", "E"]})
diff_types2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2.0,3.1,4.2], "c": [2, 4, 5]})
same_types = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2.2,3], "b": [2,3,4], "c": [2, 4, 5]})
same_types2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["A", "C", "E"], "b": ["A", "C", "E"], "c": ["A", "C", "E"]})

print(is_same(diff_types1))
# False

print(is_same(diff_types2))
# False

print(is_same(same_types1))
# True

print(is_same(same_types2))
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solve this. Here is one solution:

```
all(x == df.dtypes[0] for x in df.dtypes)
```

It returns true if all the columns have the same data type.

This single liner first creates a list of booleans by comparing all the entries in `df.dtypes` to the data type of the first element. The `all()` function returns true if all the entries are `True`